# Microsoft Graph Get access on behalf of a user

Tags: angular

Cannot getting an access token by sending a POST request to the /token endpoint from angular to Azure AD.

As mentioned in this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user), after getting an ahthorization with success, i try to get an access token from Azure AD with Angular 6 but my request does not seem to reach the Azure AD endpoint.

If I execute the request from postman using the same parameters, I get a response.

I do not find what is wrong in my request?

Thank you in advance for your help !

```
getToken(tokenId: string) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Host': 'login.microsoftonline.com'
      })
    };
    const body = new HttpParams()
      .set("client_id", "my_client_id")
      .set("scope", "user.read offline_access")
      .set("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:3000/")
      .set("grant_type", "authorization_code")
      .set("client_secret", "my_client_secret")
      .set("code", tokenId);

    this.http.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token", body.toString(), httpOptions).toPromise()
    .then(res => {
      // success
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.error = JSON.stringify(err);
    });
  }
```

There is an error :

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/token' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

i tried to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' to the header but it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution : Angular cannot request to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my_tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token" because of the CORS limitations.
So, i post the authorization code to my backend, the backend make the request to get the access token from Azure AD and return the token and the refresh token to Angular.

ps : do not forget "offline_access" scope parameter when getting the first authorization code to be sure to getting the "refresh_token" later !!!